# Can I upgrade the size of my Fusion Drive from 1TB to 3TB?

Tags: imac, hardware, upgrade, fusion-drive

I bought a new iMac last summer and went with the 1TB Fusion drive. It works well, but is already full. Is it possible to upgrade the size of the fusion drive myself? Can I buy a 3TB internal drive and just swap out the existing 1TB drive?

Does anybody have experience with this or are there any blogs you know about? I have been doing lots of research but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your exact model but [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2309+and+2374+Hard+Drive+Replacement/1634) is an example how to replace hard drive.

Before starting consider that you should also know

1- how to back up the current dive

2- how to install the operating system

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have replaced a HD before, I am mainly interested in upgrading the standard HD component of the fusion drive, to give me more space. Is that possible?